# Need a HTML to show a SQL table

Tags: php, html

I need to make the HTML table to show an SQL table, but it won't show up.

I have no idea, why it won't show up.

Here's the code.

```
<h1> <img src="gag3.png" width="454" height="70" alt="Velkommen!"></h1>
      <table width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="0" summary="">
        <tbody>

            <?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pwd = '';

$database = 'test1';
$table = 'text';

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");

// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>      

        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Now i really want it to show inside the table there, i want it to show the PHP,

Comment: What shows up? Any errors? There's some funky ass HTML going on in that PHP statement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Srry truth, And no tomhallam. it dosnt show up with anything :(

Comment: Before `// printing table rows`, you `echo` a `</tr>`.  This is probably making the table invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You have no opening `<tr>` in that snippet. Also consider using `<th></th>` for your table headings. You also need to echo the headings!

```
// printing table headers
<tr>     
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)         
{         
$field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
echo "<th>".$field."</th>       
}         
echo "</tr>\n";
```

You also don't need the \n in there; `<tr></tr>` automatically makes a line break for the next row. I don't know how those affect the HTML; consider removing them if it still doesn't work?